# Geometric Network and Replicas in Enterprise GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, geometric-network, replication

Are we supposed to use the split tool in a replica of geometric network gdb? When a consultant sends back the gdb and we sync it to the parent it throws a geometry error for the newly inserted segments that were created by the split. All they did was split a single pipe and add attributes.

My assumption is error is coming from the globalIDs. It seems like using the split tool, it preserves the original ID for one of the segments and generates a new one for the other one. Then when we sync, it assumes we just moved the old pipe without disconnecting it and we are trying to add a pipe in-between them.

Anybody had similar issues?[image]